# Howto pass %-character as parameter to stored function

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I'm trying to use the mysql's native function `DATE_FORMAT` inside a stored function, but it's not working as expected. I've created a small function to demonstrate this.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `date_format_nl`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `date_format_nl` (v DATE, f VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
  BEGIN

    DECLARE ret VARCHAR(255);

    SET lc_time_names = 'nl_NL';
    SET ret = DATE_FORMAT(v, f);

    RETURN ret;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

When using `SELECT date_format_nl("2014-01-08 10:29:00", "%d %M %Y")` I would expect the result to be `08 januari 2014`, but the actual result is `d M Y` (the format stripped).

When writing this, I figured that I had to escape the "%"-character, but I rather would not have to escape it in the argument itself (`SELECT date_format_nl("2014-01-08 10:05:00", "\%d \%M \%Y")` which does not even work!). How do I prevent mysql from stripping the "%"-character?

[image]

Comment: I don't get it... Your exptected format should be: 08 januari 2014?? Because thats what i get while using your code. "SELECT date_format_nl("2014-01-08 10:29:00", "%d %M %Y")"

Comment: Works perfectly for me without escaping %. Using version 5.1.41

Comment: I don't get it either then. Probably the version? Using 5.5.34. I've edited my post and added a screenshot.